# "JSON editor" for windows?

Tags: json, windows

Is there any JSON program for Windows, like Cocoa's [JSON Editor](http://www.cocoajsoneditor.com/index.html) ?

It's important that it's visual easy, and that you can by clicking adding new objects etc.

Comment: https://onlinejsoneditor.com is the one you are looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found one [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-pad/). Simple, and visual easy to use.